# How to update a TextView multiple times

Tags: android

I'm new on Android Development and I encountered a problem while updating multiple times a TextView when the user clicks the button to update that, it only updates once.
My app is about a shopping cart where the user selects an specific pizza, and specific drink and the amount of pizzas he wants, and then it shows the price, but only the first time, and I want to update the textview everytime the buton "+" is clicked.

```
    Integer total = 1;
    double porcion = 3.5; //every single pizza
    double bebida = 2.0; //the drink
    double totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
    String totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);

    // This method increases the amount of pizzas
    botonmas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total++;
            tv1.setText(total.toString());
            dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
        }
    });

    // This method decreases the amount of pizzas
    botonmenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(total > 1){
                total--;
                tv1.setText(total.toString());
                dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Variable total is the amount of pizzas selected.

Comment: I have 2 TextViews, one shows the amount of pizzas selected (this one updates) and the other TextView shows the price the customer has to pay (but only updates the first time the user clicks the button "+")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not update your `totalAmount` when you called onClicked

add this in your `onClick()`

```
totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
```

EDIT: FULL EXAMPLE:

```
Integer total = 1;
double porcion = 3.5; //every single pizza
double bebida = 2.0; //the drink
double totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
String totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);

// This method increases the amount of pizzas
botonmas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        total++;
        tv1.setText(total.toString());
        totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
        totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
        dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
    }
});

// This method decreases the amount of pizzas
botonmenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(total > 1){
            total--;
            tv1.setText(total.toString());
            totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
            totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
            dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never updating `totalAmount2`. So it will only ever show the initial value.

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(total > 1){
                total--;
                tv1.setText(total.toString());
                // update totalAmount2 before showing it! <<-------
                dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify code:

```
botonmenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(total > 1){
        total--;
        tv1.setText(total.toString());
        totalAmount = (total * porcion) + bebida;
        totalAmount2 = String.valueOf(totalAmount);//Effecting line Change
        dinero.setText(totalAmount2);
    }
}
```

});